# Using infinite scroll w/ a MySQL Database

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, infinite-scroll

I found a nice ajax/jquery infinite scroll plugin ( http://hycus.com/2011/03/15/infinite-scrolling-like-new-twitter-with-php-mysql-jquery/ ) that I was able to mold well to my content, but I'm having one issue -- it only calls the loadmore.php script once. Let me show the code:

In my index.php file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
            $.ajax({
                url: "loadmore.php?lastid=" + $(".postitem:last").attr("id"),
                success: function(html){
                    if(html){
                        $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                    }else{
                        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

This section calls my loadmore.php file and sends it the id of the last post. This only works the first time I scroll to the bottom of the page, it loads the entries from loadmore.php but doesn't call loadmore.php again. My loadmore.php file has the following code:

```
<?php

include('./includes/config.php');

if($_GET['lastid']){
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM db WHERE id < "'.$_GET['lastid'].'" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,3';
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($rec = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {

    [SET MY VARS]

    ?>

    [HTML & PHP DISPLAYING MY POST]

    <?php
    }
}

?>
```

The 3 posts that show up after the first ajax call come up perfectly, exactly the way I want them to show with the correct data. But I can't get the next 3 posts to show up after the first 3 show up.

So if I have 5 posts by default on my index.php, I scroll to the bottom, ajax calls 3 more posts, they display perfectly, but nothing displays after that even though there are plenty of posts left to display. Where's my problem, ajax/jquery wizards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "if" condition is only satisfied the first time you scroll. So essentially, the event is getting fired, not when you scroll to the bottom of the page, but when you start scrolling. Replace your code with the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var loading = false;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var h = $('#postswrapper').height();
        var st = $(window).scrollTop();

         // the following tests to check if 
         // 1. the scrollTop is at least at 70% of the height of the div, and 
         // 2. another request to the ajax is not already running and 
         // 3. the height of the div is at least 500. 
         // You may have to tweak these values to work for you. 
        if(st >= 0.7*h && !loading && h > 500){
            loading = true;
            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
            $.ajax({
                url: "loadmore.php?lastid=" + $(".postitem:last").attr("id"),
                success: function(html){
                    if(html){
                        $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                    }else{
                        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                    }
                    loading = false;
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Not working quite yet, but I like where it's headed. What's the point of limiting it to 70% of the height of the div, and making sure that the div is at least 500?

With this script implemented nothing loads after the primary content.

Comment: I tried changing your version to:

if(st == $(document).height() - $(window).height() and !(loading)){

Kind of a combination of yours and the original, but that doesn't work either...

Comment: I assumed that you want to load the data as you are scrolling to the bottom of the page. 70% says that once you have scrolled close to 70% of the current data, start loading more data. 500 is because, if you div is small enough that it fits on the window, you don't need to scroll. Try removing the h > 500 and see how it works.

Comment: st == $(document).height() - $(window).height() will only work the first time. after that, st value is never equal to $(document).height() - $(window).height(), so your ajax call never happens. so don't use that.

Comment: Tried removing h > 500, and lowering .7 to .2 and that didn't work either. Any other thoughts? How can I have it trigger at the bottom of the page always until there's no more content?

My initial page isn't that long, it has maybe 300px to scroll until it hits the bottom.

Comment: Do you see any errors in your javascript console? did you try putting an alert right after the if condition to see if the condition is being met? Also, try changing to var st = $('#postswrapper').scrollTop();

Comment: I have firebug but don't know how to use it (i'm terrible with JS and basically just guess and check until it works).

I made the change you suggested and that didn't work. I added an alert directly after $(window).scroll(function(){ and that didn't go off, so something strange is happening...

Comment: Replace if(st >= 0.7*h and !loading and h > 500){ with if(st >= 0.7*h && !loading && h > 500){. This is what happens if you switch between programming in python and programming in JS.

Comment: Replaced and that still didn't work, although that makes sense and should definitely stay. I put an alert directly after the function should be triggered, before the if statement, and that alert pops up, so the scroll function works, but it never gets inside the if statement (that alert doesn't pop up).

Is there still a syntax error somewhere?

Comment: OK, I started removing some of the criteria and found the problem resides with the st >= .7*h condition. If I remove that condition, then everytime I scroll it goes inside the if and posts some content. When that condition is in the if statement then when I scroll to the bottom of the page nothing happens.

Comment: I changed it to .2, and added () around each conditions and it's working much better now! Just have to toy with the percentage to get it precisely how I want it to work. Thank you so much!

Comment: This gets kinda picky, but can you think of any other way besides using a percentage for that criteria? I'd like it to execute the loadmore.php basically everytime you're 200px from the bottom of the screen, not as a factor of the size of the content wrap because as posts are added, the ajax call is made more frequently instead of at a constant rate (like say every 3 posts it's called to get 3 more).

Answer (score 2):

Would the above code example with the following mods work to trigger the function at a fixed height from the bottom??

Add:

```
var trigger = $('#postswrapper').height() - 250;
```

And change:

```
if (st >= 0.7*h && !loading && h > 500) {
```

to:

```
if ((st == trigger) && (!loading) && (h > 500)) {
```