# Infinite Scroll with MySQL Data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have followed help located in this topic: [Using infinite scroll w/ a MySQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492545/using-infinite-scroll-w-a-mysql-database)

And have gotten close to getting this working properly. I have a page that is displayed in blocks using jquery masonry, in which the blocks are populated by data from a mysql database. When I scroll to the end of the page I successfully get the loading.gif image but immediately after the image it says **"No more posts to show."** which is what it should say if that were true. I am only calling in 5 posts initially out of about 10-15, so the rest of the posts should load when I reach the bottom of the page but I get the message that is supposed to come up when there really aren't any more posts.

Here is my javascript:

```
var loading = false;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {   
            var h = $('.blockContainer').height();
            var st = $(window).scrollTop();
            var trigger = h - 250;

              if((st >= 0.2*h) && (!loading) && (h > 500)){
                loading = true;
                $('div#ajaxLoader').html('<img src="images/loading.gif" name="HireStarts Loading" title="HireStarts Loading" />');
                $('div#ajaxLoader').show();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "blocks.php?lastid=" + $(".masonryBlock:last").attr("id"),
                    success: function(html){
                        if(html){
                            $(".blockContainer").append(html);
                            $('div#ajaxLoader').hide();
                        }else{
                            $('div#ajaxLoader').html('<center><b>No more posts to show.</b></center>');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is the php on the page the blocks are actually on. This page initially posts 5 items from the database. The javascript grabs the last posted id and sends that via ajax to the blocks.php script, which then uses the last posted id to grab the rest of the items from the database.

```
$allPosts = $link->query("/*qc=on*/SELECT * FROM all_posts ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 5");
        while($allRows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($allPosts)) {
            $postID = $link->real_escape_string(intval($allRows['post_id']));
            $isBlog = $link->real_escape_string(intval($allRows['blog']));
            $isJob = $link->real_escape_string(intval($allRows['job']));
            $isVid = $link->real_escape_string(intval($allRows['video']));
            $itemID = $link->real_escape_string(intval($allRows['item_id']));

            if($isBlog === '1') {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE blog_id = '".$itemID."' ORDER BY blog_id DESC";
                $result = $link->query($query);
                while($blogRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $blogID = $link->real_escape_string($blogRow['blog_id']);
                    $blogTitle = $link->real_escape_string(html_entity_decode($blogRow['blog_title']));
                    $blogDate = $blogRow['pub_date'];
                    $blogPhoto = $link->real_escape_string($blogRow['image']);
                    $blogAuthor = $link->real_escape_string($blowRow['author']);
                    $blogContent = $link->real_escape_string($blogRow['content']);  

                    //clean up the text
                    $blogTitle = stripslashes($blogTitle);
                    $blogContent = html_entity_decode(stripslashes(truncate($blogContent, 150)));           

                    echo "<div class='masonryBlock' id='".$postID."'>";
                    echo "<a href='post.php?id=".$blogID."'>";
                    echo "<div class='imgholder'><img src='uploads/blogs/photos/".$blogPhoto."'></div>";
                    echo "<strong>".$blogTitle."</strong>";
                    echo "<p>".$blogContent."</p>";
                    echo "</a>";
                    echo "</div>";

                }
            }
```

Here is the php from the blocks.php script that the AJAX calls:

```
//if there is a query in the URL
if(isset($_GET['lastid'])) {

//get the starting ID from the URL
$startID = $link->real_escape_string(intval($_GET['lastid']));
//make the query, querying 25 fields per run
$result = $link->query("SELECT  * FROM all_posts ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT '".$startID."', 25");

$html = '';
//put the table rows into variables
while($allRows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $postID = $link->real_escape_string(intval($allRows['post_id']));
    $isBlog = $link->real_escape_string(intval($allRows['blog']));
    $isJob = $link->real_escape_string(intval($allRows['job']));
    $isVid = $link->real_escape_string(intval($allRows['video']));
    $itemID = $link->real_escape_string(intval($allRows['item_id']));

    //if the entry is a blog
    if($isBlog === '1') {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE blog_id = '".$itemID."' ORDER BY blog_id DESC";
        $result = $link->query($query);
        while($blogRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $blogID = $link->real_escape_string($blogRow['blog_id']);
            $blogTitle = $link->real_escape_string(html_entity_decode($blogRow['blog_title']));
            $blogDate = $blogRow['pub_date'];
            $blogPhoto = $link->real_escape_string($blogRow['image']);
            $blogAuthor = $link->real_escape_string($blowRow['author']);
            $blogContent = $link->real_escape_string($blogRow['content']);  

            $blogTitle = stripslashes($blogTitle);
            $blogContent = html_entity_decode(stripslashes(truncate($blogContent, 150)));

            $html .="<div class='masonryBlock' id='".$postID."'>
                    <a href='post.php?id=".$blogID."'>
                    <div class='imgholder'><img src='uploads/blogs/photos/".$blogPhoto."'></div>
                    <strong>".$blogTitle."</strong>
                    <p>".$blogContent."</p>
                    </a></div>";

        }
    }
    echo $html;
}
```

I have tried using the jquery infinite-scroll plugin, but it seemed much more difficult to do it that way. I don't know what the issue is here. I have added alerts and did testing and the javascript script is fully processing, so it must be with blocks.php right?

**EDIT:** I have made a temporary fix to this issue by changing the sql query to `SELECT * FROM all_posts WHERE post_id < '".$startID."' ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 15`

The blocks are now loading via ajax, however they are only loading one block at a time. The ajax is sending a request for every single block and they are fading in one after another, is it possible to make them all fade in at once with jquery masonry?

Answer (score 2):

I seen your code in another answer, and I would recommend using the LIMIT functionality in MySql instead of offsetting the values. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM all_posts ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT '".(((int)$page)*5)."',5
```

This will just take a page number in the AJAX request and get the offset automatically. It's one consistent query, and works independent of the last results on the page. Send something like page=1 or page=2 in your jQuery code. This can be done a couple different ways.

First, count the number of elements constructed on the page and divide by the number on the page. This will yield a page number.

Second, you can use jQuery and bind the current page number to the body:

```
$(body).data('page', 1)
```

Increment it by one each page load.

Doing this is really the better way to go, because it uses one query for all of the operations, and doesn't require a whole lot of information about the data already on the page.

Only thing to note is that this logic requires the first page request to be 0, not 1. This is because 1*5 will evaluate to 5, skipping the first 5 rows. If its 0, it will evaluate to 0*5 and skip the first 0 rows (since 0*5 is 0).

Let me know any questions you have!

Comment: I had a `LIMIT` function in there at first if you look at the 3rd code block in my original question, it wasn't working that way so I did the `WHERE post_id < $startID` method and it worked... but not exactly how I want it to. It only grabs one entry per AJAX request. Can you please explain your method a little bit more so I can try to do it your way?

Comment: You have: LIMIT '".$startID."', 25 but this is not necessarily what we want. If you pass the start ID of 10 (since the assumption is you are passing the last post visible on the page). This only works if every ID is sequential and none are skipped. If you have posts 7 through 12 deleted, you would have 10 total rows in the DB. But the statement LIMIT 12,25 would start at the 12th row, which doesn't exist, and return nothing. LIMIT takes a row offset and goes by that. It does NOT use any form of ID's within the rows in any way. LIMIT 0,5 would start at row #0 (first) and go for 5 rows.

Comment: Oh! And LIMIT XX,25 will start at row XX and return the next 25 rows. I think 25 should be 5 if you want 5 rows at a time.

Comment: Thank you for that great explanation! I only have 5 there right now because I don't have that many items in the database yet. When finished and populated I will want to pull about 15-20 entries at a time. So how should I go about building the page query you mentioned? I have a pagination script for my site, but it's a very odd pagination script that I wrote a few years ago and I don't see how it would work with what you've explained to me... If you don't mind assisting me we can do it via email or here if you'd like...

Comment: Do you have any counter on the page? Maybe a COUNT on the masonryBlock element will work. $(".masonryBlock").length could work, as it will get the current count of items on the page. All you would have to do is pass that, not worrying about any other last_id elements or anything. If you have a pagination script, you could pass the page number and multiply it by the amount you display per page. Could you develop your pagination script into something like that? Do you have access to the page number they are pageination'ing? Also, I'll email you. But let's keep this on SO.

Comment: You do not have any website displayed in your profile, or any other contact information. If you would like to give me some contact information, you are welcome. However, it is entirely your call.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing any debugging?

If you are not already using, I would recommend getting the firebug plugin.

Does the ajax call return empty? If it does, try echoing the sql and verify that is the correct statement and that all the variables contain the expected information. A lot of things could fail considering there's a lot of communication happening between client, server and db.

In response to your comment, you are adding the html in this piece of code:

```
if(html){
     $(".blockContainer").append(html);
     $('div#ajaxLoader').hide();
}
```

I would do a **console.log(html)** and **console.log($(".blockContainer").length)** before the if statement.

Comment: I changed the sql query to `$result = $link->query("SELECT  * FROM all_posts WHERE post_id < '".$startID."' ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 5");` and the ajax call is finally bringing in data from the database, but now masonry isn't positioning the newly appended elements.

Comment: Does $(".blockContainer") exist?

Comment: Yes. Thats the container that all the masonry blocks are in.